# Add custom button in admin wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a button to upload all posts to a table.I wrote this code

```
function add_xml_import_button() {
  ?>
  <div class="alignleft actions">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="export_xml">
      <input type="submit" name="export_xml" value="export XML">
    </form>
  </div>
  <?php
}
add_action('manage_posts_extra_tablenav', 'add_xml_import_button');

function handle_xml_export() {
  if (isset($_POST['export_xml'])) {
    $xml_data = "<posts>";
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
      $xml_data .= "<post>";
      $xml_data .= "<title>" . $post->post_title . "</title>";
      $xml_data .= "<content>" . $post->post_content . "</content>";
      $xml_data .= "</post>";
    }
    $xml_data .= "</posts>";
    
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="posts.xml"');
    echo $xml_data;
    exit;
  }
}
add_action('admin_post_export_xml', 'handle_xml_export');
```

I've got two buttons appearing on the page. One in the header of the table. The second in the footer. Only one works, the one in the footer. After a bit of reading about the `manage_posts_extra_tablenav` hook, I found that you can specify where to display the button using `$which`. For example `'top' === $which`. If top or bottom is specified, only one button remains. But it does not work. Can anyone tell me what my mistake is

Comment: What exactly do you need? Two buttons or one button? Should they both do the same? Why would you need `$which`? Do you want to place one button on top or one button below? Or both? What does « it doesn’t work » mean?